# Woocommerce - Get SKU in product single page

Tags: wordpress, get, woocommerce, singlepage

I want go get the SKU in my product single pages in Woocommerce. I tried `<?php get_sku(); ?>` which is a featured function according to the Woocommerce docs (http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) but it will just break the loop. What to do?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`get_sku()` is a method of the WC_Product class, so you need to have a product on which to call it, like this:

```
<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>
```

This should work if you are inside the WooCommerce product loop, and is what is used in the WooCommerce template files.   If you don't already have a reference to the product object, you may need to add the following line at the top of the file in order to access it:

```
global $product;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job! I had tried the first of these without result but when I add the global $product; line it works just fine!